# I am not able to change the color of my checkbox's innerArea

Tags: checkbox

My checkbox is

`import React from "react";

function Checkbox({ onClickProp, isCheckedProp, checkBoxDisableProp }) {
return (

);
}
export default Checkbox;`

and CSS is

```
bigger-checkbox
{
  cursor: pointer;
  transform: scale(1.25);
  background-color: #cea325 !important;
  color: #61dafb;
}

input[type="checkbox"]
{
  background-color: #cea325 !important;
}

bigger-checkbox:disabled
{
  cursor: not-allowed;
  transform: scale(1.25);
}
```

and my webpage is

[image]

I just want to change the color

Comment: Can you provide checkbox UI code ? so can get better idea

Comment: Hi @Riddhi,

here is the code


`import React from "react";

function Checkbox({ onClickProp, isCheckedProp, checkBoxDisableProp }) {
  return (
    <input
      disabled={checkBoxDisableProp}
      className="bigger-checkbox"
      type="checkbox"
      checked={isCheckedProp}
      onChange={onClickProp}
    />
  );
}

export default Checkbox;`